# What is the mysterious relationship between `fchown()` and `flock()`?

Tags: macos, unix, posix, darwin

Reading the man pages for `fchown`, I find this statement:

> > The fchown() system call is particularly useful when used in conjunction with the file locking primitives (see flock(2)).

Here's the mystery: the man page for `flock(2)` makes no mention of `fchown` or even how ownership affects it in general.

*So can anyone explain what happens when `fchown` and `flock` are used together and why it's so "useful?"*

I'm developing for macOS (Darwin), but I find the same statement (and lack of an explanation) in Linux, BSD, POSIX, and virtually every other *NIX man page I've searched.

**Backstory** ('cause every great villain has a backstory):

I have a set-UID helper process that gets executed as *root*, but spends much of its time running as *user*. While it's running as *user*, the files it creates belong to *user*. Good so far.

However, occasionally it needs to create files while running as *root*. When this happens, the files belong to *root* and I want them to belong to *user*. So my plan was to create+open the file, then call `fchown()` to change the ownership back to *user*.

But a few of these files are shared and I use `flock()` to block concurrent access to the file and now I'm wondering what will happen to my flocks.

Comment: It's curious that `fchown()` is selected and not others of the '`f`-clan' (`fstat()`, `fchmod()`, …). Perhaps the connection is that `flock()` and the other '`f`-clan' functions work with file descriptors, and so are not affected by villains renaming a file — while you keep the file descriptor open, you will refer to the same file, even if it is renamed, or your access permissions via the path used to open the file are revoked, etc. But that applies to `fstat()` and `fchmod()` too — I'm not sure if there's another significance to `fchown()`.  You don't often use `fchown()` in my experience.

Comment: 'Tis also curious that `flock()` is not part of POSIX (not POSIX 2008, nor 2004, nor even 1997).  The `lockf()` function is in POSIX.  And the `fcntl()` function has locking capabilities too.